# How is the cost to stay at the Rooster Inn determined?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

When I first started the game, it cost 30en every time I wanted to stay at the Rooster Inn to recover. Now it's up to 40. It feels like the game is trying to give me a push along to get on with it, but I really would rather take my time. If the cost keeps increasing, however, I may need to stop dawdling.

How is the cost at the inn determined?

Comment: In the original game, IIRC it was based off of your party's combined levels.

Answer (score 5):

The cost of the inn is determined by the highest level party member in the current active party. After the first few floors, the cost will become rather negligible, as drops are worth more and more, while the inn seems to increase cost by about 5 En per level.